# Groovy - Split by hyphen '-' and concatenate values at index 1 and 2. if index 2 does not exist. return index 1 values only

Tags: if-statement, groovy, split, return, concatenation

Writing an Groovy script to Split by '-' and concatenate values at index 1 and 2. if index 2 does not exist. return index 1 value only. Can you pls help with the code below.

input 111-222-333 - should return 222333 as output.

input 111-222 - should only return 222 as output.

```
import com.sap.it.api.mapping.*;
import com.sap.gateway.ip.core.customdev.util.Message;
import java.util.HashMap;

def String split(String input,MappingContext context){
def output = input.split("-");
{
    if (output[2].exists()) // also tried the statement if (output[2] != null). and did not work.
    {
        return output[1]+ output[2];
    }
    else
    {
        return output[1];
    }
}
}
```

Thanks,
Vicky.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can not safely check for the existence of something inside an array
by attempting to access it by index.  You will get an exception, that
you accessed an index out of bounds if your index is greater or equal to
the `length` of the array.

```
def mySplit(s) {
    def xs = s.split("-", 3)
    xs.length>2 ? xs.tail().join() : xs[1]
}

assert mySplit("111-222-333") == "222333"
assert mySplit("111-222") == "222"
```

(note that this will fail for an input, that does not contain `-` and is
left as exercise due to lack of specification in the question)